# MongoDB Realm ObservableObject, SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, mongodb, swiftui, realm

I'm new to SwiftUI, so please bear with my mistakes.

I'm trying to follow this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eu-YaVvsbjQ), but instead of downloading a JSON, I'm using a MongoDB Realm, specifically `Realm.asyncOpen`. Here is my `ObservableObject` class:

```
class Gallery: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var results: Results<tiktoks>
    
    init(results: Results<tiktoks>) {
        let user = app.currentUser!
        let configuration = user.configuration(partitionValue: user.id)
        Realm.asyncOpen(configuration: configuration) { (userRealm, error) in
            guard error == nil else {
                fatalError("Failed to open realm: \(error!)")
            }
            print("connected somehow")
            self.results = userRealm!.objects(tiktoks.self)
    }
            
}
}
```

I kind of followed this [guide](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/observableobject) too, as I was getting some errors since I'm not using the `Decodable` structs from the YouTube tutorial. (edit: as I'm looking more deeper I actually might need it, but I had some trouble with them while trying to use them)

But when I try to get the variable from a different struct, I get this error:

```
@ObservedObject var gallery = Gallery
Type 'Gallery.Type' cannot conform to 'ObservableObject'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols
```

What am I doing wrong here? Has anyone got MongoDB Realm working with `ObservableObject`?

Comment: What's the thought here `init(results: Results<tiktoks>)`? Are you initializing it with existing results?

Comment: Oh oops.. might’ve put that on accident. I don’t need to import existing results.

Comment: I think you wanted to say `gallery = Gallery()` - you need the parentheses to instantiate the class, if you want to use it.

Comment: Yeah corrected that too, but now there's another problem in the actual mongoDB function now.

Comment: So there were a number of coding errors in the question but those have been corrected but now there's another error - but we don't know what that is. If you can clarify the question we can take look.

Comment: I couldn't figure it out so I just ended up not using @ObservedObject, and just put the mongoDB function in an `init()` function when my view loads. It works and so far it looks like it refreshes when it needs to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get `ObservableObject` to work, so I just put the MongoDB function in an `init()` function when my view is rendered.

```
struct Home: View {
    
    let gallery: Results<Tiktoks>
    let user = app.currentUser!
    let realm: Realm
    
    init() {
        let configuration = user.configuration(partitionValue: user.id)
        self.realm = try! Realm(configuration: configuration)
        let data = realm.objects(Tiktoks.self)
        self.gallery = data
        print(data)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                LazyVGrid(columns: [ // ...
```

It looks like it also re-renders the view when the database is changed too.